# How to confirm the path to the Schema Definitions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What is a schema definition and How to get the path to the schema definitions?

Is this the path 
D:\Data\db

Answer (score 0):

Schema is structural organization of data stored in database.

According to MongoDB documentation:

> Data in MongoDB has a flexible schema. Collections do not enforce
>   document structure.